# How to bind hotkey of 'tab out' extension to "enter" in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The tabout extension in VS works fine. I just want to rebind it to "enter" as it seems easier & more natural to hit after i m done inputting the data between the quotes.

But it does not have rebind feature in VS code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a thread [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/8154). It seems like you can rebind it with:

```
   { "command": "-tabout" },
   { "key": "enter", "command": "-tabout" }
```

They do say that this causes some issues in how it actually goes about doing it's task, so "...if you are at the start of a line that begins with a quote, instead of adding a tab space, it brings you into the quote." I imagine this would mean that there would be more issues with using enter instead of tab. Another commenter recommended this configuration to circumvent this issue with TabOut.

```
{
    "key": "shift+'",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": { "snippet": "\"$1\"$0" }
},
{
    "key": "`",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": { "snippet": "`$1`$0" }
},
{
    "key": "shift+9",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": { "snippet": "($1)$0" }
},
{
    "key": "[",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": { "snippet": "[$1]$0" }
},
{
    "key": "shift+[",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": { "snippet": "{$1}$0" }
}
```

I think better than doing any of those is just to remap the right arrow to a key that is more comfortable to be hit from the home row. This can be done without even installing extensions. It can be found here:

- "Preferences" -> "Keyboard Shortcuts" -> "cursorRight" -> "^ F" (ctrl+F on Mac).